# Azure Traffic Manager - API Management service degraded?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-traffic-manager

I have configured the Azure API Management Service - Premium as shown below

[image]

added two regions/locations

[image]

and I could access it as shown below

[image]

When I try to setup the Azure Traffic Manager as shown below

[image]

[image]

the endpoints are degraded

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How do I put Azure Traffic manager in front of the APIM?

Comment: So, if you do an http get to https://myapiabc-westus-01.regional.azure-api.net/
, it does give you a 200 OK? Is it a public reachable endpoint?

Comment: It works with HTTPS, should I will check HTTP too?

Comment: Yes, and I see that in your curl request you are not using the root endpoint (https://myapiabc-westus-01.regional.azure-api.net/) but to a specific endpoint. Your probe is targeted at the root however.

Comment: OK does it mean that I have use either the /status-xxxx endpoint or the endpoint that actually returns 200 status?

Comment: I am not sure what kind of backend you have, is it a self-developed application? If so, you can create a  specific health check you can use. https://www.ibm.com/garage/method/practices/manage/health-check-apis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that I have to configure the Traffic manager Health check as shown below

[image]

as well as I have to configure the Azure API management as shown below

[image]

it is started working